# Volume of a solid revolution 1.4

Tags: calculus, analysis, definite-integrals, volume, solid-of-revolution

What is the volume of the solid generated by revolving about the $y$-axis, the area bounded by the parabola $y=(x-1)^2-1, y=2$, and the $y$-axis?

I'm confused with the outer and inner radius. I am a little bit skeptical in using the formula of the volume of solid revolution. I don't know where to substitute those values in the formula.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: I have tried to improve the readability of your question by introducing [Tex](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/). It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you. This is edited so well by you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volume of a Solid 1.3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201663/volume-of-a-solid-1-3)

Comment: Most likely duplicate of [Volume of a solid 1.3](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201663/volume-of-a-solid-1-3) which received a good answer and [Volume of a solid revolution 1.5](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2201736/volume-of-a-solid-1-5?noredirect=1&lq=1) which was closed as a duplicate of the first link.

Answer (score 1):

In order to gain some intuition about this problem, have a look at the following figure (produced by Wolfram alpha).

[image: solid of revolution]

What is interesting about this problem is that the area enclosed between the two functions, namely $f_1(x) = (x-1)^2 - 1$ and $f_2(x) =2$, intersects with the $y$ axis which is the axis of rotation.

We therefore need to revolve the surface enclosed between $f_1$ and $f_2$ and $x\geq 0$ with area

$$A = \int_0^{1+\sqrt{3}}(f_2(x) - f_1(x))\mathrm{d}x$$

This can be easily seen to be

$$V = \int_0^{1+\sqrt{3}}2\pi (f_2(x) - f_1(x))x \mathrm{d}x $$

If, on the other hand, we assume that the revolution creates a cavity in the solid body, then we need to subtract the following volume

$$
\Delta V = \int_0^{1+\sqrt{3}}2\pi (f_2(x) - f_1(-x))x \mathrm{d}x
$$